# why first QMenu initializing so heavily?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qmenu

simplest script: its just show context menu with 2 elements after running
but first QMenu initializing is more slowly when i expected 0_o

it seems Qt to be not optimized for such a usage scenario?

after run script:

- Main Window show immediately
- but  context menu show after ~0.7-1.2 sec after running

it's not a problem for me, but i'm just wondering - why is reason that behaviour of Qt
and ways to improve perf if it possible

- perf_counter() show, that all script processes ( until -> menu.exec(QCursor.pos()) ) executed by 0.06-0.09 sec
- i compiled script by "Nuitka", but speed is the same
- on windows os i have "autohotkey" script, and it run custom context menu instantly
- run platform windows 10 18362 64x
- python 3.10.4 virtual env not use
- run script *.pyw without console output

differ codes i trial - result is similar
this is one of:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QAction, QMenu, QApplication)

"""
for Qt6:
from PyQt6.QtGui import QCursor, QAction
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (QMenu, QApplication)
"""

def context_menu():
    menu = QMenu()
    
    action1 = QAction("Exit option")
    action1.triggered.connect(lambda: sys.exit())
    
    action2 = QAction("Second option")
    action2.triggered.connect(lambda: print("You have clicked the second option"))
    
    menu.addAction(action1)
    menu.addAction(action2)
    
    sys.exit(menu.exec(QCursor.pos()))

app = QApplication([])
context_menu()
```

Comment: If that's just the whole program, the explanation is simple: it takes some time to load the Qt library (the base is about 30-40mb). Generally, one doesn't have a whole program that just opens a menu and (most importantly) then quits.

Comment: yeah, sadly, that a Qt Window show instantly, seems like developers of Qt optimized process of init Main Window but context menu load in secondary priority - something like ~delayed loading~

Comment: No, it's a bit more complicated than that, and, the issue still remains, the library takes time to load, some objects are obviously "faster" to show due to their simplicity (a menu is *not* simple, an empty window is, the size is irrelevant), but the main bottleneck is the program initialization. And it has almost nothing to do with Qt, it would probably have similar results with other toolkits.

Comment: tkinter Menu loads faster ...
i understand - tk builtin and it's dramatically lighter than qt rich lib

Comment: tk is not only extremely lightweight, but also very limited. The Qt base library alone is composed by more than a thousand classes and tens of thousands of functions. You've to choose between performance and features. As said, a whole program that just needs to show a menu and quit probably needs something different (IIRC provides some limited api to show standalone context menus), or maybe it should *not* quit at all, but keep running in background waiting for being recalled again.

Comment: @musicamante, Thanks for your response, it's a bit clarified (confirmed my guesses) of runtime inner processes,   
as i wrote, menu init speed it's not so critical, also i have an alternative in "tk" for realize cases sort of, 
this question are related mainly to an my "academic interest" than with some serious discomfort

Comment: As said, consider your options. If the menu is always the same, you may consider having a persistent application that keeps running in background. This doesn't automatically mean that you must load it at startup: there are ways to detect if the *same* application is already running, and eventually call it by various means (sockets). In this way, you may only have that slight delay only on first run, but then the menu will probably appear instantly, as long as the application keeps running.